# Disabled is undefined javascript error

Tags: javascript

When I try to do this:
`document.getElementById('idOfCheckBox').disabled = disabled;` I get error : disabled is undefined.
What can be the reason?

Comment: it must be `document.getElementById('idOfCheckBox').disabled = 'true';`

Comment: Thanks...but that does not work. No error, but the checkbox is not disabled.

Comment: I have tried that in plain HTML and it worked. Maybe you just have to write `true` (with out the **apostrophe**). Plus, be sure to check that `document.getElementById('idOfCheckBox')` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to see what `document.getElementById('idOfCheckBox')` gives you? Is it a HTMLDOMElement with an attribute disabled? If not, maybe you got the wrong element?

Try `console.log(document.getElementById('idOfCheckBox'))` if you have access to a fairly modern browser.

Comment: Thanks very much. The input type comes out to be hidden although it is part of the new Ext.grid.CheckColumn

Answer (score 0):

- No such element exists, or
- No such variable `disabled` exists in the current scope.

Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: disabled is not a variable. it is an attribute of an element.

Comment: @Kaushik, The 'disabled' to the right of '=' is a variable, is it not?

Comment: @Kaushik, then what is it really?

Comment: @Kaushik: Then that is your problem. If it's an attribute of an element, you forgot to tell your code what element that is.